# SAS procedure for calculating LOC Line-of-Organic-Correlation?

Tags: regression

I am using SAS PROC Reg to develop an OLS regression equation for a random sample of 190 observations.  These observations contain the Old_Area of_oF_Polygons (var X) and the true area of GIS polygons (var Y).  The REG equation is then used to score a larger dataset with PROC Score.  In cases where there is no real dependent or independent variable in the calssic sense, it seems that the Line-of_Organic Correlation (LOC)-- which minimizes the sum of right triangles formed by vertical and horizontal lines--might be more appropriate.
Is there a SAS PROC that can do that?  Would there be much difference between this and the OLS REG approcah ?